# Type inference for lazy variable

Tags: swift

I have a lazy variable declared as follows:

```
private lazy var cachedTonesByChord: [Note: [Note]] = self.tonesByChord()
```

... where `self.tonesByChord()` has following signature:

```
() -> [Note: [Note]]
```

Now, when I remove the type:

```
private lazy var cachedTonesByChord = self.tonesByChord()
```

... compiler complains:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

Why can't the compiler infer the type automatically?

Comment: This is not a problem with inferring the type but that you can not access `self` in this context. Can't you make `tonesByChord` a static method? If not you'll need two properties: one to store the dictionary and a computed one to lazily create the dictionary and return it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It relies on bunch of properties.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Swift Programming Language:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_306)

> If a stored property’s default value requires some customization or setup, you can use a closure or global function to provide a customized default value for that property. Whenever a new instance of the type that the property belongs to is initialized, the closure or function is called, and its return value is assigned as the property’s default value.

Instead of a global function you want to use an instance method to set the value of the property but this isn't possible, because

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other property values from within your closure, even if those properties have default values. You also cannot use the implicit self property, or call any of the instance’s methods.

So, the problem here is that you are calling a method on self.

**Update** 
On a second thought this seems strange, because you have declared a `lazy` property, which will be created when your instance already exists.

Comment: The lazy variable could be accessed during initialization so it cannot use `self` for initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Because your subclass may implement `tonesByChord()` with different return type.

For example:

```
class Chord {
    private lazy var cachedTonesByChord = self.tonesByChord()

    func tonesByChord() -> [Note:[Note]] {
        return [Note("C") : [Note("C"), Note("E")]]
    }
}
class ChordSub:Chord {
    func tonesByChord() -> [Note] {
        return [Note("A"), Note("B")]
    }
}
```

If the class is `ChordSub`, the Compiler cannot determine which `tonesByChord()` should be called without explicit type requirement.

Comment: This makes sense. But then why declaring the method as `final` doesn't help?

Comment: I can explain it that `tonesByChord() -> [Note]` in subclass is not overriding `tonesByChord() -> [Note:[Note]]`, but defining *another* method. **But** declaring the **class** as `final` also doesn't help. well... I have no idea :D